# Best way to find the correct load time of a webpage with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am doing performance testing of a website.

I see two options, but I'm confused about which one is right:

1. Simply hit website Url and under `HTTP Request Defaults` check `Retrieve all Embedded resources`.
2. Use Jmeter Http recorder, and under `Url patterns to exclude`, check `Add suggested excludes`.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

1. Start with your option 1
2. Tick `Parallel downloads`
3. Put `6` in the number of threads for parallel downloading
4. Filter out all **external** resources via `URLs must match` section. If your application makes outside calls to images, banners, etc. you need to filter out them so your load test would focus solely on your application domain(s), example exclusions look like:

   ```
   ^((?!google|facebook|pinterest|twimg|doubleclick|whatever).)*$
   ```

   amend the line according to your needs

   [image: JMeter HTTP Test Plan]
5. Add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to mimic browser cache. Real browsers download these "embedded resources" but do it **only once**, on subsequent requests the resources are being returned from memory or disk cache and no actual requests to the server are being made
6. Don't forget [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) and [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to represent browser cookies and headers
7. If your application uses AJAX requests you need to simulate them as well as JMeter is not a browser and it doesn't execute client-side JavaScript

More information: [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)

Comment: If there are lets say 100 users opening this webpage together and all these users are opening this page for 2nd time and hence all the users have webpage images and other embedded resources cached in browser. How can i find the page load time in this case. If I put No of users as 100 and use cache manager, Jmeter does not share cache between threads as per the documentation.

Comment: Each virtual user is independent and has its own cache.

Comment: Then how can i check the load time of a webpage when the content is being loaded from cache.